# Jmeter: Cannot record website with basic HTTP Aut

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I need to do a HTTP recording from one of the website for my company
I usually use Basic HTTP Auth to access the website: `http://<user>:<pass>@website.com`

The website use single sign on.

When starting my proxy 8888 and then Jmeter, I am able to record from a website in my company that does NOT have single sign on, but I cannot record from the ones that do. It does throw a pop up to login, but after 3 or 4 times of inputting proper credentials, it throws the bellow error:

```
No Internet
There is something wrong with the proxy server or the address is incorrect
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) can provide [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) possibilities, most probably it's [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on#Integrated_Windows_Authentication) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on#Kerberos-based)

You can try adding properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your test plan, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) for more detailed explanation and some configuration samples

Comment: It doesn't work for the recording only for the execution